# how to use reCaptcha 2.0 in asp classic with multiple image uploader?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, recaptcha, enctype

i am using asp classic in which i use **recaptcha 2.0** when i used **enctype="multipart/form-data"** my image uploader work fine but recaptcha response is **false** and when i remove enctype="multipart/form-data" on form tag recaptcha work fine but **not image uploader** please help me

recaptcha method

If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
        Dim recaptcha_secret, sendstring, objXML

```
    ' Secret key
    recaptcha_secret = "secret key"

    sendstring = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" & recaptcha_secret & "&response=" & Request.form("g-recaptcha-response")

    Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objXML.Open "GET", sendstring, False

    objXML.Send
Dim oJSON,jsonstring,result,data,success
    Set oJSON = New aspJSON
```

result = (objXML.responseText)

```
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
oJSON.loadJSON(result)

Set objXML = Nothing

success = oJSON.data("success")
if success = "True" then

    TestCaptcha ="True"
else
    TestCaptcha ="False"

end if     
    Set objXML = Nothing
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Request.form("g-recaptcha-response")` when posting a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, as the ``Request.Form`collection is not available.

Instead, use your Upload component DLL property (usually `form`too).
For example, with the Persists ASPUpload component, use :

```
Set Uploader = Server.CreateObject("Persits.AspUpload")`
Dim myFormField
myFormField = Uploader.Form("g-recaptcha-response")
```

You can then use your variable `myFormField` to pass to Google ReCaptcha, like this :

```
sendstring = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" & recaptcha_secret & "&response=" & myFormField
```